# Call javascript function with parameters and read the return values in page load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, cookies

I have javascript function in default.aspx like this:

```
 function ReadValue(Name) {
    Return value;
 }
```

Now from pageLoad method, I want to pass parameter and get the return value to server side variable.

Comment: Can you please provide additional information. Do you wish to set value to a server side element (note: server side variable can not be used in javascript). If that is your case you can try hiddenfield control to set the value.

Answer (score 1):

To send data from the client to the server, you have to ... send data from the client to the server. :-) Typically, you do that with [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), although there are other ways as well (doing a standard form `POST`, or even doing a `GET` of some kind although if your server is going to act on the information by changing server state, you shouldn't use `GET`).

Comment: Thanks.. First of all, tell me how to Call this method on server side passing the parameter durin page_load?

Comment: If you're talking about a JavaScript function in a `script` element inside `default.aspx`, you can't. It runs **client**-side, not server-side. You can code a call to it in the script, e.g. `ReadValue('foo');`, but that will happen in the user's browser, not on the server. You can then post whatever the data is you get back to the server using Ajax, but that's very, very different from this stuff happening on the server.

Answer (score 0):

another way is by putting the values in sever side controls 
for exmaple in jquery you can do something like this:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
$("#txtMyTextBoxID").val('my value')
```

}

aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBoxID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best idea is to make a Javascript function and make a server side Hiddenfield. Access that hidden field and store your values (comma delimited) in your hiddenfield. and access it on page load.

I do it this way.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" />
document.getElementById("<%= hdn.ClientID%>").value = "your value";
```